# How do you generate xsd namespace prefixes in the resulting output file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xsd

I've gone over multiple topics and solutions that talk specifically about this issue. None have worked or I fail to understand what I am doing wrong.

I would like for the namespace prefixes to accompany the element names in the resulting xml output file.

I'm am using the XSD command with Visual Studio 2008 from the VS Command Prompt

Here's my xsd schema for **Trial.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Junk"
       targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
       xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
       xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:import namespace="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" schemaLocation="TestSchema.xsd" />

<!-- Start LookType -->
<xs:complexType name="LookType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="gx:TimeSpan" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="longitude" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- End LookType -->

<xs:element name="Te" type="LookType" />

</xs:schema>
```

Here's my xsd schema for **TestSchema.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="TestSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
       xmlns="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
       xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="TimeSpan" type="gx:GXTimeSpanType" />

<!-- Start GXTimeSpanType -->
<xs:complexType name="GXTimeSpanType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="begin" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="end" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- End GXTimeSpanType -->

</xs:schema>
```

I´m generating the resulting class file `Trial.cs` by using `xsd TestSchema.xsd ./Trial.xsd /c /l:cs /n:T`

In a program I assign these junk values and write them to file using `XmlDocument`, `XmlSerializer` and `FileStream`

```
T.LookType te = new T.LookType();
te.longitude = "34.444";
te.TimeSpan = new T.GXTimeSpanType();
te.TimeSpan.begin = "2010-02-26T20:22:00Z";
te.TimeSpan.end = "2010-02-26T20:23:42Z";
```

I've excluded the method that saves out the file using `XmlDocument`, `XmlSerializer` and `FileStream` as it is a little thicker then I'd like to post unless that is part of the problem.

This is what I get in the resulting file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Te xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

  <TimeSpan xmlns="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <begin>2010-02-26T20:22:00Z</begin>
    <end>2010-02-26T20:23:42Z</end>
  </TimeSpan>
  <longitude>34.444</longitude>
</Te>
```

This is what I want in the resulting file. Notice the `gx:TimeSpan` element and the `xmlns:gx` namespace definition being added to the main `Te` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Te xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <gx:TimeSpan>
    <begin>2010-02-26T20:22:00Z</begin>
    <end>2010-02-26T20:23:42Z</end>
  </gx:TimeSpan>
  <longitude>34.444</longitude>
</Te>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter on which element the prefixes are declared on, as long as they're declared before they are used. Any code that doesn't like this is broken.

Perhaps because it doesn't matter, XML Schema has no way to influence on which element the prefixes are declared, or which prefix is used.

Comment: I read somewhere that <TimeSpan
> xmlns="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"> and

xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
<gx:TimeSpan>

was syntactically equivalent. However google earth's timeline slider will only function properly if the <gx:TimeSpan> tag is present in the xml. So i need to generate this over the former.

Comment: Importing types described here in section 5.4 Importing Types http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#import  
Example 4 has the format I want, with the qualified and unqualified elements. Wondering why serialization of my schema does not produce this type of output.